# Where is the definition of __warn_memset_zero_len in string3.h

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

Recently I moved my project to ubuntu 16.04 from ubuntu 14.04. When I compiled my project with gcc 4.8.5, which is installed from os repository, I encountered an error, "undefined __warn_memset_zero_len". I've never seen that error on ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.4.

__warn_memset_zero_len, which is declared in string3.h, is called from memset to warn programmer's mistake. To reproduce the error I made the following sample code and compiled it with `gcc --save-temps test_mem.c -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wall -O1 -v -Wl,-v`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
     char str[] = "almost every programmer should know memset!";
     memset (str, 1, 0);
     puts (str);
     return 0;
}
```

This code is also compiled only in ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.4. So, First, I assumed that the new libc might be missing the definition of __warn_memset_zero_len. To find out the definition, I compared the old libc of ubuntu 14.04 with that of ubuntu 16.04. The both versions do not have it and only have the function's declaration in string3.h. I was wrong. :<

As the next step, I assumed gcc might drop the reference to the function during compile as it is a special warning function. However, the object files created by both systems still have the reference, checked by nm. Then, the source code still need the definition of __warn_memset_zero_len. My thought moved on shared objects linked with the test code.

```
/usr/bin/ld --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 \
--hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
-z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib \
-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. 
test_mem.o -v -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc \
--as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

This is the link commmand gcc uses to link the test code on ubuntu 14.04. I looked up all symbols of the linked objects and libraries, but cannot find __warn_memset_zero_len. The mystery is getting serious.

As the final try, I assumed that the attribute "**warning**" __warn_memset_zero_len's declaration uses might allow the old gcc to compile a code without definition. So I made the following test code.

```
extern void __warning_test (void) __attribute__((__warning__ ("test_warning")));

int main(){
   __warning_test();
   return 0;
}
```

Now, I can get the undefined symbol error on both systems.

```
/tmp/ccN1UbZh.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `__warning_test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no clue why the compilation succeed in the old system without the definition of __warn_memset_zero_len and why it fail in the new one. In addition, why does the custom function which looks exactly same with __warn_memset_zero_len fail even on the old system? Do you have any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__warn_memset_zero_len() is declared in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a, which is a implicit library for gcc. you can use nm command to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why, but libc.a in ubuntu 16.04 does not include that symbol.

Comment: @Hani As shown by the function name, this function is used to check arguments of memset. From gcc5.0, which is the default compiler on Ubuntu16.04,  this argument checking is implemented in gcc, so it became un-necessary to include a checking function in libc.a. Therefore it is removed in Ubuntu16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an intentional error, being caused by this line:

```
memset (str, 1, 0);
```

The declaration for `memset` is:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Note that your size / length value is zero. What you really want is perhaps something like this:

```
 char str[] = "almost every programmer should know memset!";
 memset (str, 0, sizeof str);
```

Edit: rereading your post, I realise you might be intentionally creating this error? But perhaps you're trying to read too much into it. It could be that at some late point in compiler optimization, gcc sees the problem, but too late to give a specific error, so causes a link error to force a stop.

And another thought: there's a slight chance the compiler could put `str` into write-protected memory, because it thinks that is a `const` string. If that happens, your `memset` is going to die anyway. I *think* you're okay though as long as `str` is stored on the stack (i.e. declared inside a function, and not static).